# Check a multidimensional array input in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an input type hidden in a loop, so it's a multidimensional array and it has one input name.
How can I check if there is any value in it? Like any value or element?
This is the code: (the array is generated in php in a loop)

```
echo "<td class='$border'>
    <div class='DropZonePers'></div>
    <input type='hidden' value='' name='pers[$dag][$j]'/>
</td>";
```

What I have tried in js:

```
if($(".pers").length !> 0) {
   alert("No!");
   return false;
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please remove the "C" tag from this question; it has nothing to do with C.

Comment: I just did, I didn't notice the tag

Comment: @anantkumarsingh dude I can't put the name as a value, the value is created in a drag & drop system

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grab all input elements that have a name that starts with "pers" and see if any are not empty

```
function persIsEmpty() {
    var empty = true;
    $('input[type="hidden"][name^="pers"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0 && $(this).val() != '') {
            empty = false;
        }
    });
    return empty;
}
```

`//...so something like`

```
if (persIsEmpty()) {
    alert("No!");
    return false;
}
```

See: https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

`$(".pers")` searches for an element with *class name* "pers". Your hidden input does not have that class name. The following will search for the input with `type="hidden"` and check to see if its value is an empty string.

```
if ($('input[type="hidden"]').val() == '') {
    alert("No!");
    return false;
}
```

NOTE: If you have more than one hidden input, and you want to uniquely search for the input specified in your post, give it an *id* or a unique *class* to search by.

With class:

```
$('.className').val()
```

With ID:

```
$('#IDName').val()
```

Comment: I can't do that because some of the input might be empty, the user is not supposed to fill in all the values